# Show coverage results for each directory specified in jest.config.js

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I have specified different coverage thresholds in `jest.config.js` for different subdirectories:

```js
  coverageThreshold: {
    ['./src/server']: {
      statements: 90,
      branches: 90,
      lines: 90,
      functions: 90,
    },
    ['./src/client']: {
      statements: 80,
      branches: 80,
      lines: 80,
      functions: 80,
    },
  }
```

When I run `jest --collectCoverage`, I get a report on the overall coverage levels for the entire `src` directory, not the individual `server` vs `client` directories. The only way I have figured out to get that information is to force them to fail. For example, I temporarily increase the coverage levels to 100 on everything. This results in the test run failing, and it outputs something like the following:

```
Jest: "./src/server" coverage threshold for statements (100%) not met: 59.91%
Jest: "./src/server" coverage threshold for branches (100%) not met: 43.69%
Jest: "./src/server" coverage threshold for lines (100%) not met: 59.83%
Jest: "./src/server" coverage threshold for functions (100%) not met: 51.39%
Jest: "./src/client" coverage threshold for statements (100%) not met: 81.73%
Jest: "./src/client" coverage threshold for branches (100%) not met: 72.1%
Jest: "./src/client" coverage threshold for lines (100%) not met: 82.02%
Jest: "./src/client" coverage threshold for functions (100%) not met: 81.23%
```

Is there any way to get Jest to report the `client` vs `server` coverage amounts on a successful test run?